# Creating R dataset

Tags: r

I want to create dataset in R so that I load into R session as follows:

```
data(mydatasetname)
```

I tried following:

```
values<- read.table("mydatasetname.txt") 
save(values,file="value.rda")
```

but when I type following command to load data:

```
data(values)

Warning message: In data(values) : data set ‘values’ not found
```

Can anybody help?

Nitin

Comment: @Tyler's answer is better form (and what I'd recommend to you as well), but if you want to do it with data() see my comment to his answer.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect `load` may be what you're after though I'm not sure.  If you load the data in directly there's no need to make the call to data as in:

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars                             #rename mtcars to mtcars2
save(mtcars2, file="mtcars2.rda")             #save mtcars2 
rm(mtcars2)                                   #remove from envir
mtcars2                                       #gone : (
load("mtcars2.rda")                           #load mtcars2 
mtcars2                                       #and you're back : )
```

Now you only need to use `load(mtcars2.rda)` from now on and your data is there.

If you want to use `data()` you may have to create a package with your data and load the package and then use data though I'm not 100% sure on this.

Comment: The help page for ?data suggests it can be used to load non-package (local) data and that it even is somewhat smart about doing so (identifying file types) but it requires a local data directory (as if in a package). E.g., 

system("mkdir data"); write.csv(1:5, file = "./data/temp.csv"); data(temp)

works. Still, I get the impression this is considered more of a convenience function than good form and that the OP should save() and load() -- or even better saveRDS() and readRDS() to avoid name clobbering.

Answer (score 1):

I did pretty much the exactly steps you did, except I saved it in a data subdirectory:

```
save(values,file="data/value.rda")
```

I then removed the object:

```
rm(values)
```

and used ls() to make sure it was gone.

When I tried to load it back in, I used the value of the filename **value** instead of **values**:

```
data(value)
```

and that worked fine.   If I try "data(values)" I get the error that you see.

So the bottom line seems to be: you need to use data(value), not data(values), and it might have to be in a data subdirectory.